# Determinant of a modal matrix used in diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If A $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is diagonalized as $P^{-1}AP=\Lambda$ with P the modal matrix composed of the eigenvectors of $A$, is there a general way to determine the determinant of $P$, except that it is not equal to zero?

Answer (score 2):

No. The problem begins with the fact that the eigenvectors themselves are not determined uniquely. Given $P$ you can multiply the first column by any non-zero scalar $c$ and obtain $P'$. Then you will still have $P'^{-1}AP' = \Lambda$ and $\det(P') = c \det(P)$. When you diagonalize $A$, the determinant of $P$ will depend on which eigenvectors you choose from each eigenspace and can be an arbitrary non-zero scalar.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the help. In the case of symmetrical matrices and orthogonal diagonalization, I understand that the columns in the (orthogonal) modal matrix are unique? I believe you can switch the columns (also switching the eigenvalues in $\Lambda$) and therefore only inverting the sign of the determinant which should then be equal to ±1? Is this correct?

Comment: @tonymacaroni Regarding symmetric matrices: first of all, you could also multiply a column by $-1$, and that would flip the sign of the determinant.  Second of all, whenever there is a repeated eigenvalue, the associated orthonormal eigenvectors can be any orthonormal basis for the corresponding eigenspace.